# Is Angular material design usable with Dart?

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-material

Is [Angular material design](https://material.angularjs.org/#/) usable with Dart?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use Angular.js components/directives in Angular.dart. There was an attempt started very recently to port it to Dart https://github.com/akserg/angular.dart.material/blob/master/README.md